# Excel VBA Worksheet Function "Filter" has "Type mismatch" error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Below is my attempt at filtering "0" from my list of values. When assigning "result" it gives me the error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

```
Function FilterVals(list_of_vals As Range)

Dim result As Variant
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(list_of_vals, list_of_vals <> 0)
FilterVals = result

End Function
```

I think the error may be within this syntax "list_of_vals <> 0".

"A1:A5<>0" works fine in an Excel Sheet, but perhaps not so simple in Excel VBA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In using `Worksheetfunction.Filter`, the second argument has to be an array of `{True, False,..}`, **oriented properly** (*i.e. vertical or horizontal depending on what's being filtered*) for your argument.

One way of producing that, in your code, might be:

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(list_of_vals, Evaluate(list_of_vals.Address & "<> 0"))
```

*assuming `list_of_vals` is a 1D array*

Answer (score 0):

I needed to filter based on a cell value.  I tried Ron Rosenfeld's approach as is, but it needed tweaking.  This worked:

```
Dim result() As Variant

With WorksheetFunction
    result = .Filter(.Transpose(Evaluate(list_of_vals.Address)),_
    .Transpose(list_of_vals.Address & "=" & criteria_cell.Address)))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this a bit more, and think I understand it pretty well now.   Here's a test sub to show the results of my exploration. For data, place the following starting in A1.

| Return | Filter |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | Fruit |
| Oranges | Fruit |
| Steak | Meat |
| Chicken | Meat |
| Cookies | Dessert |
| Cake | Dessert |
| Carrots | Veggies |
| Broccoli | Veggies |
| Cabbage | Veggies |
| Watermelon | Fruit |
| Bananas | Fruit |
| Green Beans | Veggies |
| Ice Cream | Dessert |

```
Sub WSF_Filter_Test()
 'Note:  As Ron pointed out, the 2nd .Filter argument must be an array of boolean values.  All of the 'Evaluate' calculations below result in boolean values.
    With WorksheetFunction
        'works
         x1 = Evaluate(Range("B2:B14").Address & "=" & Range("B2").Address) '2d array 
         result1 = .Filter(.Transpose(Evaluate(Range("A2:A14").Address)), .Transpose(x1)) '1d array with 4 elements as expected
         
         x1b = Evaluate(Range("B2:B14").Address & "=" & Range("B2").Address) '2d array
         result1b = .Filter(.Transpose(Evaluate(Range("A2:B14").Address)), .Transpose(x1)) '2d array with 4 elements in each dimension as expected

         x2 = Evaluate(Range("B2").Address & "=" & Range("B2").Address) 'single value
         result2 = .Filter(.Transpose(Evaluate(Range("A2").Address)), Array(x2)) '1d array with a single element
         
         x3 = Evaluate(Range("B2").Address) = "Fruit"
         result3 = .Filter(.Transpose(Evaluate(Range("A2").Address)), Array(x3)) '1d array with a single element
        
        'Type Mismatch at runtime
        'x4 = Evaluate(Range("B2:B14").Address) = "Fruit"
        
        'This runs, but the resulting 2d array has only 'Error 2029' (#NAME) errors
        x4 = Evaluate(Range("B2:B14").Address & "= Fruit")
        
        
        'Works
        'Build the boolean array by looping through each cell in the Filter column
         Dim x5()
         Dim rngReturn5 As Range
         Dim rngFilter5 As Range
         
         Set rngFilter5 = Range("B2:B15")
         Set rngReturn5 = Range("A2:A15")
         
         ReDim x5(1 To rngFilter5.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
         For i = 1 To UBound(x5)
            x5(i, 1) = rngFilter5.Cells(i) = "Fruit"
         Next i
         result5 = .Transpose(.Filter(Evaluate(rngReturn5.Address), x5)) '1d array with 4 elements as expected
      
      
         Dim x5b()
         Dim rngReturn5b As Range
         Dim rngFilter5b As Range
         
         Set rngFilter5b = Range("B2:B15")
         Set rngReturn5b = Range("A2:B15")
         
         ReDim x5b(1 To rngFilter5b.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
         For i = 1 To UBound(x5b)
            x5b(i, 1) = rngFilter5b.Cells(i) = "Fruit"
         Next i
         result5b = .Transpose(.Filter(Evaluate(rngReturn5b.Address), x5b)) '2d array with 4 elements in each dimension as expected
         
         
        'But if you're looping through the range and want a single column returned, might as well just build the array and avoid the Filter worksheetfunction
         Dim result6()
         Dim rngReturn6 As Range
         Dim rngFilter6 As Range
         Dim k as Integer, l As Integer
         
         Set rngFilter6 = Range("B2:B15")
         Set rngReturn6 = Range("A2:A15")
    
         For k = 1 To rngFilter6.Rows.Count
            If rngFilter6.Cells(k) = "Fruit" Then
                l = l + 1
                ReDim Preserve result6(1 To l)
                result6(l) = rngReturn6.Cells(k)
            End If
         Next k
    End With
End Sub
```